# Regularly "File not found". nginx + php-fpm

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, server

I'm using web server nginx + php-fpm and Ubuntu 14.04.2

I have regularly following error when opening a webpage page:

> File not found

Config is right. After restarting nginx or php-fpm a site works perfectly.

I tried to upgrade nginx, php-fpm, reinstall them but it didn't help. The error occurs sometimes every few hours, sometimes every minute. I am tired to restart it.

Comment: How can we help you?

Comment: There's not really enough information here to answer this question. What pages are resulting in this error? Are they pages that exist? Please add more information to clarify the problem.

Comment: @Leggendario any tips will help me. I don't know how to google it. tried many tips for solving but they not helps me

Comment: @EdCottrell yes. Page is exist. One page — index.php. http://take.ms/iFNyC look the uptime. Site in development and no one visits. Log doesn't has any errors.

Comment: @kotchuprik 8 years have passed, and I have also encountered this problem now. Have you solved this problem

Answer (score 0):

if your nginx config is right ,i think this reason is the php config.

may be you shoud to config the `php.ini` file

make sure the field `doc_root` is empty .

just like this: `doc_root =`

[More info here](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.doc-root)

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I'm certain it's a php error but my doc_root is empty.. any ideas?